# I manage to disable scroll on body when menu mobile is open , but desktop / body page always going back to the top when i open menu mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, next.js

I'm manage to disable scroll on body , no problem with that , thanks to SO !
But when i open my mobile menu , **body always going back to the top .**

If i remove

> overflow : hidden

Scroll isn't anymore disable on body , but body doesn't going back to the top when i open my mobile menu .

My css class .overflowHidden is add on body and html when burgermenu is open .

```
    const [showBurgerMenu, setShowBurgerMenu] = useState(false)


const handleOnClick = () => {
    const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
    burger.classList.toggle('active');
    setShowBurgerMenu(!showBurgerMenu);
    if (showBurgerMenu === false) {
        document.querySelector("body").classList.add("overflowHidden");
        document.querySelector("html").classList.add("overflowHidden")
    } else if (showBurgerMenu === true) {
        document.querySelector("body").classList.remove("overflowHidden");
        document.querySelector("html").classList.remove("overflowHidden");
    };
}
```

my css class

```
.overflowHidden {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  touch-action: none;
  -ms-touch-action: none;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Thanks for your help
PS : i'm on nextJS don't know if it's important

Comment: Try removing the position : fixed; it resets the position of the body, and change height : 100% to height : 100vh;

Comment: Thanks ! after two days of messing arround ! you are a life saver !

Comment: @Xanthous, may be you should post as an answer for us to upvote it

Comment: You're right I will post an answer, it might be helpful to someone in the future

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you apply `position : fixed;` and then return you will reset the position of your body because a **fixed** element isn't part of the page's flow

We must then change it's height from 100% to 100vh so the element's (in this case the body) height takes the whole screen and prevent any scrollbar to appear since we defined a height.

```
.overflowHidden {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  touch-action: none;
  -ms-touch-action: none;
  /* position: fixed; we get rid of this line which resets the flow of the page */
  /* height: 100%; we change 100% to 100vh */ 
  height: 100vh;
}
```